# rsync "skipping non-regular file" when cloning my Aperture library

Tags: osx, rsync

I am trying to use rsync to maintain a backup copy of my Aperture library. When I run the sync command to see what would happen this is the outcome:

```
rsync --dry-run -r "/Volumes/Data/Aperture Library.aplibrary" "/Volumes/Backup"

skipping non-regular file "Aperture Library.aplibrary/Database/BigBlobs.apdb"
skipping non-regular file "Aperture Library.aplibrary/Database/Faces.db"
skipping non-regular file "Aperture Library.aplibrary/Database/History.apdb"
skipping non-regular file "Aperture Library.aplibrary/Database/ImageProxies.apdb"
skipping non-regular file "Aperture Library.aplibrary/Database/Library.apdb"
skipping non-regular file "Aperture Library.aplibrary/Database/Properties.apdb"
```

The "file" command says that at least the ".db" file is a "SQLite 3.x database". How can I sync these files with rsync?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

It would seem those files are symlinks.

To copy them as symlinks, use `--links` (or `-l`).

To hard copy the files they are pointing to, use `--copy-links` (or `-L`).

For details see the `SYMBOLIC LINKS` section in `man rsync`.

Comment: My files are regular text files, not links still gave me this error message. Not sure why. However, these file do get copied to destination. A little strange.

Answer (score 74):

Use `-a` instead of `-r`. `-a` means to reproduce file hierarchies, including special files and permissions. `-r` only means to recurse on directories. For a backup, you want `-a`.

Comment: I'd say this is the practical solution, though the --links clarification is useful. I use `rsync -hiva --log-file=log.txt source dest` most of the time.. i like hiva ~ winter as a mnemonic

Comment: Not necessarily.  For example I might not have permission to change groups on the destination.   Generally you run with the maximum options you have permissions for if you want a complete backup, and you use options like --fake-root to try and simulate the rest.

Comment: _"For a backup, you want `-a`"_, unless you're cloning to or from a **FAT** or **exFAT** filesystem, in which case `-a` is broken and you want `-hvrtDl --modify-window=1`. I mention this [in my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1785111/425838).

Comment: From man: "       --archive, -a
              This is equivalent to -rlptgoD.  It is a quick way of saying you want recursion and want
              to  preserve almost everything.  Be aware that it does not include preserving ACLs (-A),
              xattrs (-X), atimes (-U), crtimes (-N), nor the  finding  and  preserving  of  hardlinks
              (-H).

              The  only exception to the above equivalence is when --files-from is specified, in which
              case -r is not implied.
"